# delete column in csv in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, csv

I have the following format for my CSV file that I downloaded online and need to parse it. I want to be able to get rid of the 'unit' column. How can I go about doing this? I want to be able to do it as I parse through the file and not copy it to a different file because the file is very large. Thanks!

```
 <radio>,<mcc>,<net>,<area>,<cell>,<unit>,<lon>,<lat>,<range>,<samples>,<changeable>,<created>,<updated>,<averageSignal>
UMTS,262,2,801,86355,,13.28527,52.521711,37,7,1,1282569574,1300175362,-91GSM,262,2,801,1795,,13.276605,52.525348,5714,9,1,1282569574,1300175362,-87
```

Comment: You didn't try anything

Comment: "*not copy it to a different file because the file is very large*" If you have sufficient memory, you can keep the contents in memory. But, otherwise, read the file line by line, remove the field from each line, write out to new file, when successfully done, rename the new file to the original one.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV would allow you to read in the file, store all the columns apart from the one you don't need and write it back out. Have a go at something and then update your question if you get stuck.

Comment: *"because the file is very large"* Are you saying that a second copy of the file won't fit on your disk storage? Why do you want to remove that column at all? Can't any other software just ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $col_to_delete = '<unit>'; 

chomp ( my @header = split /,/, <> );
my @newheader = grep { not $_ eq $col_to_delete } @header; 

print join (",", @newheader),"\n";

while ( <> ) {
   chomp;
   my %row;
   @row{@header} = split /,/; 
   print join (",", @row{@newheader}),"\n"; 

}
```

Reads STDIN line by line, and prints as you go, so you don't need lots of memory.

You can probably do it via in-place editing, but you'll want to test it to make sure that it works satisfactorily first. You'd do this by setting `$^I`, but really you're better off creating two files, because it's shockingly easy to clobber one accidentally.